# Skip submodule during maven release

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I intend to use one of my maven submodules to distribute shared test code and resources. The submodule is built and injected as test-scoped dependency to the rest of the submodules. How do I prevent the test jar to be released while releasing the rest correctly?

I use maven release plugin as `release:prepare` and `release:perform` pair.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best option I can think of is http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html#skip . So in the pom of this specific module include the maven-dependency-plugin like this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <skip>true</skip>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This will ensure that it will never be deployed; no SNAPSHOT nor released version.

Comment: This apparently does not work if you are using the maven release plugin to release to maven central (with nexus-staging-maven-plugin, as per instructions from  http://central.sonatype.org/pages/apache-maven.html)

Comment: The question is about the maven release plugin, so does setting skip true for the maven deploy plugin get considered by the maven release plugin?

Comment: There's less magic done by the maven-release-plugin than you expect, see https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/perform-release.html . So in the end maven-release-plugin calls `mvn deploy`, respecting all configuration.